# Prettier insert blank line after list item in Markdown file

Tags: prettier

Currently the `Prettier` will format a Markdown file like this:

````
1. Example
```bash
$ cat dummy.txt
```
````

and insert a blank line after the list item like this:

````
1. Example

```bash
$ cat dummy.txt
```
````

I want the code block to align to the indentation same as the list item. Do you have any idea of how to configure `Prettier` NOT to insert a blank line after the list item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on version 1.12.0 and up, you can use a [range ignore](https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore#range-ignore):

> This type of ignore is only allowed to be used in top-level and aimed to disable formatting for auto-generated content, e.g. `all-contributors`, `markdown-toc`, etc.

While its meant for protecting auto generated content from being formatted, (like a markdown table of contents), it works for this as well:

````
<!-- prettier-ignore-start -->
1. Example
```bash
$ cat dummy.txt
```
<!-- prettier-ignore-end -->
````

In my tests, this seems to work.  You are *suppose* to be able to use a one line disable comment as specified [here](https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore#markdown), but my tests indicate that doesn't work for this scenario.  I am guessing something with the numbered list being adjacent to the code block causes it not to work.